# Load local html file in webview android

Tags: android, html, webview, android-studio, local

I am trying to load the contents of a html file in a webview in android. However, it gives me the "Webpage not available error". If I try websites such as google or yahoo, they work.

The html file are under src > main > assests > index.html

Can someone help me with this issue. Thank You.

Following is my code :

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

WebView mWebView;
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

XML File :

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: I hope your asset folder is not really named `assests`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The html file should be placed in the `assets` folder (note the spelling), which will belong in the root directory of your project.

So move

```
src/main/assests/index.html
```

to

```
assets/index.html
```

In an Android Studio project use this folder:

```
/app/src/main/assets/index.html
```