# Can I open local html links inside a webview?

Tags: android, html, hyperlink, android-webview, local

I have a webview set up that works.

It loads a page from the root of the assets folder called index.html

I want it a html link in that index.html to be able to open a local link that can be found in assets\catalyst\index.html

I have added the link in the root index file, but when i click the link in the app, it crashes.

I have tried

`<a href="file:///android_asset/catalyst/index.html">`

`<a href="./catalyst/index.html">`

but neither stop it crashing.

i assume it is some sort of permissions.

i set a lot of "getSettings" on the original webview, that I hoped would cover all the permissions but to no avail.

This is the link in the root index.html

`<a href="file:///android_asset/catalyst/index.html"><img src="./homepage/catalystimage.jpg" alt="catalystimage"></a>`

This is in the Java file allowing the loadurl of the first webview.

`````
        webView=findViewById(R.id.webviewid);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        WebView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);````

i want it to load the local index.html file from the subfolder.

it crashes the app.
`````

Comment: Enable first debugging for webview. Open your first HTML file. Open your desktop browser -> developer tools -> remote device and select your android device. Now you can click on your href link and look at the console tab to see what error is being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

The html file should be placed in the `assets` folder (note the spelling), which will belong in the root directory of your project.

So move

`src/main/assests/index.html`
to

`assets/index.html`
In an Android Studio project use this folder:

`/app/src/main/assets/index.html`

Add this line,
`webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());`

Check it:
[Load local html file in webview android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557804/load-local-html-file-in-webview-android)

Comment: Hi Sai, thank you for taking the time to respond.

The index.html is in /app/src/main/assets/

that loads fine. it is just when i click on a html link in that index file to open the link in the position below

/app/src/main/assets/catalyst/index.html 

that it makes the app crash.

Comment: Try this,

  webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

Comment: I already have the webview.setWebChromeclient to enable the openGL elements. Would your suggestion cause a conflict?